# HQL difference of timestamps in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hql

I wrote a HQL query which seems to work fine on SQLServer but throws an exception on Oracle.
The query simply calculates the sum of durations of all tasks

```
SELECT SUM(second(t.endTime) - second(t.startTime))  FROM Task as t
```

Apparently you cannot get seconds from sysdate in Oracle. Is it possible to write a single HQL  query that will work with both databases ? or should i handle oracle separately in this case ?

**EDIT**: I forgot to add that both endTIme and startTime are `Date` types.
And the exception i get is

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, the [syntax](http://psoug.org/reference/timestamp.html) is just slightly different, which implies you'd have to do it differently.

It's `extract(SECOND from ( endtime - starttime) )`.

But, you can only [`extract`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php) seconds from a `date`. If you want seconds via this method then your column *has* to be a `timestamp` datetype.

Alternatively, and more useful as it'd work for you, I prefer the following. Oracle returns days from date-arithmetic, hence the multiplication at the end.

```
( endtime - starttime ) * 60 * 60 * 24
```

Comment: So i'd have to use a separate oracle query then ?

Comment: Unless you can convert the Oracle query to work on SQL-Server, yes. I don't know what SQL-Server returns if you minus dates from each other?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it returns a date.

Comment: @LajosArpad, it's technically an [`interval`](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html) datatype, however, when doing date-arithmetic on _dates_; this is effectively [days](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_date_arithmetic.htm).